# CSS div positioning falls apart in chrome

Tags: css

So I'm making this web page and my site layout works the way I want it to in mozilla and IE but falls apart in chrome and on my android phone. What happens is that the boxes under the header cover the #topmenu div. Any suggestions, I tried tweaking the display setting a bit but so far nothing worked?

```css
body {
/*ozadje celotne strani */    
    background-image:url("images/background_test.jpg");
    background-size:80%;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:center top;
/* zgornji spodnji rob celotne strani */    
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
/*krčenje strani*/
    min-width:40em;
    max-width:106em;
/*font celotne strani*/
    font-family:Verdana;
}
/* splošno linki */
a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
}
a:visited{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
}
a:active{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
}
a:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#999999;
}
/* cel header */
.header{
    width:70%;
    margin-left:15%;
    margin-right:15%;
    height:3.2em;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}
/* logo positioning */
#logo{
    display:inline-block;
}
/* napis na headerju */
#headersign{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-size:180%;
}
/*top menubar */
#topmenu {
    background-color:#009933;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-radius:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}

/* text position menubar */
#linkijs{
   float:left;
   display:inline;
   margin-left:5%;
}
#linkeng{
   float:right;
   display:inline;
   margin-right:5%;
}
/* podatki o knjižnici */
#leftpanel {
/*container positioning*/
    float:left;
    margin-top:1%;
    margin-bottom:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    margin-left:15%;
/*ostalo*/
    width:15%;
    height:100%;
    max-height:34em;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:1%;
    background-color:#ffffcc;
    opacity:0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    font-size:100%;
    display:inline-block;
/*vertical center tekst*/
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
/*scrollbars*/
    overflow:auto;
}
/*linkbox container*/
#rightpanel{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    margin-right:15%;
    margin-top:1%;
    width:52%;
    height:100%;
    max-height:37em;
    overflow:auto;   
}
.linkbox{
/*linkbox positinoning*/  
    margin:2%;
    float:left;
/*style*/
    background-color:#ccff99;
    padding:1%;
    width:15em;
    height:15em;
    border-radius:10px;
    opacity:0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}
.linkboxtitle{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:120%;
}
.linkboxlink {
    font-size:80%;
    color:#000000;
}
.footer {
    background-color:#009933;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:70%;
    margin-left:15%;
    margin-right:15%;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#copyright{
    float:left;
    margin-left:5%;
}
#adminmail {
    float:right;
    margin-right:5%;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <img id="logo" src="images/ijs_logo.gif" alt="logo" />
            <p id="headersign">ZNANSTVENO INFORMACIJSKI CENTER</p>
            <div id="topmenu">
                <a href="http://www.ijs.si/"><p class="menutext" id="linkijs">IJS</p></a>
                <a href="indexEN.html"><p class ="menutext" id="linkeng">ENGLISH</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="leftpanel">
            <p id="leftpaneltext">
                Institut Jožef Štefan <br />Knjižnica <br/>Jamova 39 <br/>1000 Ljubljana <br/><br/>tel: +386 1 47 73 304 <br/>fax: +386 1 47 73 152 <br/><br/>Delovni čas:<br/>pon-čet: 8:00-17:30<br/>pet: 8:00-17:00
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="rightpanel">
            <div class="linkbox" id="novosti">
                <p class="linkboxtitle">NOVOSTI</p>
                <a href = "http://greyhound.ijs.si:13795/Scripts/Allsi.asp"><p class="linkboxlink">e-knjige založbe Springer</p></a>
                <a href = "http://greyhound.ijs.si:13782/Scripts/Titsi.asp"><p class="linkboxlink">nove elektronske revije</p></a>
                <a href = "http://greyhound.ijs.si:13784/Defsi.asp"><p class="linkboxlink">novi izvodi tiskanih revij</p></a>
                <a href = "http://www.sciencemag.org/archive"><p class="linkboxlink">Science Classic</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="linkbox" id="knjižnica">
                <p class="linkboxtitle">KNJIŽNICA</p>
                <a href = "http://greyhound.ijs.si:13786/Defsi.asp"><p class="linkboxlink">predstavitev</p></a>
                <a href = "http://www.cobiss.si/scripts/cobiss?ukaz=getid&amp;sblk=c&amp;lani=si&amp;bno=50108"><p class="linkboxlink">COBISS</p></a>
                <a href = "mailto:illijs@ijs.si"><p class="linkboxlink">medknjižnična izposoja</p></a>
                <a href = "http://splet02.izum.si/cobiss/BibPersonal.jsp?init=t"><p class="linkboxlink">bibliografije raziskovalcev</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="linkbox" id="čitalnica">
                <p class="linkboxtitle">ČITALNICA</p>
                <a href = "http://greyhound.ijs.si:13782/Scripts/Titsi.asp"><p class=linkboxlink>elektronske revije</p></a>
                <p class="linkboxlink">CD ROM-i</p>
            </div>
            <div class="linkbox" id="servisi">
                <p class="linkboxtitle">SERVISI</p>
                <a href = "http://greyhound.ijs.si:13790/Defsi.asp"><p class=linkboxlink>splošno zanimivi</p></a>
                <a href = "http://greyhound.ijs.si:13787/Defsi.asp"><p class=linkboxlink>samo za lokalne uporabnike</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p id="copyright">© ZIC IJS. Vse pravice pridržane.</p>
            <p id="adminmail">spletni mojster:<a id="adminmaillink" href = "mailto:anton.verbovsek@ijs.si"> av</a></p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

I added my whole code so you guys can see what I'm talking about, hope it's not too confusing. Thanks

Comment: don't display .header as inline-block

Comment: deleting display:inline-block just breaks the layout in firefox as well. Did you mean for me to replace it and what with?

Comment: sorry, you should remove all of your inline-blocks

Comment: this makes the site fall apart even more, now the element I want to have next to eachother (rightpanel, leftpanel) are all in different lines. I honestly have no idea why this happens for some reason in chrome and on android the inline-block on #topmenu doesn't seem to work